# No secure ad-hoc network with Yosemite?

Tags: macos, security, ad-hoc

iMac (late 2009) OSX 10.10.3
iPads (a 1 and a 2) iOS 8.?

---

I am a retired IT engineer playing at being a DJ/VJ. That means I'm often in a room with lots of folks with cells and iPads. Before Yosemite, I was creating ad-hoc nets at my gigs and connecting my iPads to my iMac. It was relatively comfortable that I wouldn't have to worry about anyone screwing around with my systems, audio/video/DMX lighting.

I am getting ready to do some gigs and while checking my system, I realized there is no longer a Create Network option on my Wi-Fi menu. And from what I'm reading here, it doesn't appear I can even create one. Is this correct?

Comment: On my iMac under Yosemite, the option to create an ad-hoc network is present, but it doesn't offer you the ability to secure it al all 

Comment: Same under El Capitan (10.11 β2).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use the Imac to share a network conenction over wifi which in effect also creates a hotspot.

In preferences go to sharing. Pick network sharing in the list. It has options to set a wifi password and you can then choose to share internet from something to wifi.

Unforetuntely apple "fixed" it in mountain lion or lion that you can no longer share if you arent actually connected to another device. 
Before I could make a hotspot using ethernet as my share choice even if ethernet wasnt plugged in. Now it no longer will create the hotspot if not actually connected.

EDIT: I recently found away around this issue and the answer is listed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208060/how-to-create-a-password-protected-ad-hoc-network-on-yosemite-when-not-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1)